# Grails Application Folder Organization Best Practice

Tags: grails

I am struggling to organize domains, controller and views in Grails 2.3.8 application. The applications is quite small right now but its planned to grow bigger and I would like to organize folder structure and package naming convention little better. Ideally I would like to have following structure, but I am sure there are better approaches. I would gladly welcome the wonderful solutions you guys will have.

**Domain**

Item

Category

**Controller**

admin

```
ItemController (package = com.example.admin, namespace = admin)
CategoryController (package = com.example.admin, namespace = admin)
```

public

```
ItemController (package = com.example.public, namespace = public)
CategoryController (package = com.example.admin, namespace = public)
```

**Controller**
  admin

```
ItemController (package = com.example.admin, namespace = admin)
CategoryController (package = com.example.admin, namespace = admin)
```

public

```
ItemController (package = com.example.public, namespace = public)
CategoryController (package = com.example.admin, namespace = public)
```

**Views**

admin

```
index.gsp
create.gsp
etc
```

public

```
index.gsp
create.gsp
etc
```

The questions now are
1. Is this the right folder structure? Any pitfalls this might create
2. How do I accomplish this on grails

Answer (score 0):

Grails is a convention over configuration framework. Grails projects all follow a predefined folder arrangement, which is fully described in the documentation:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#conventionOverConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Grails application, it sets up a default Groovy/Java package. This default package (which can be changed) is used by default when you create Grails artefacts (domains, controllers, etc). I've toyed with the idea of creating sub-packages for these artefacts, but now I simply don't do that. Here's why.

Grails does a lot of stuff for you. That's fantastic because it eliminates a lot of boilerplate code and saves you time. And the more you stick with the conventions, the more Grails can do for you. And this applies to packaging. If you leave the artefacts in the default package,  that cuts down on the number of import statements. This applies not only when you create artefacts but also when you create unit tests (they use the same default package).

Your concern about putting many classes into the same package is a valid one. And since you're expecting your application to grow in size that's a likely possibility. The Grails solution is plugins. You can modularize your application into plugins and then use a *main app* to bring everything together. Each plugin would have a different package namespace.

If you want your app and its plugins to live in the same codebase, you can create a *plugins* directory in your project (as a sibling directory of grails-app). Then, create your Grails plugins within the *plugins* directory. Finally, refer to each plugin in *grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy*.

```
grails.plugin.location.'plugin-a' = './plugins/plugin-a'
grails.plugin.location.'plugin-b' = './plugins/plugin-b'
```